# Custom Eclipse Source->generate Delegate

Tags: java, eclipse, templates, delegates, wrapper

I want to create a Wrapper where the wrapped object may be null. If I go to Eclipses Source->generate Delegate Methods option I can choose a member and I'm able to select all methods. The Problem is in generating itself, because I become something like this:

```
class A {

    public boolean aMethod(){ 
        //some stuff
        return true //may also return false
    }
}

class Awrapper {

    private A myA;

    public boolean aMethod(){ 
        return myA.aMethod();
    }
}
```

but I need something like this:

```
class Awrapper {

    private A myA;

    public boolean aMethod(){
        if (myA != null) {
            myA.aMethod(); 
        } else {
            return false; // or the default for return type like 0 or null
        }
    }
}
```

There is an link stating:
"The format of the Delegate Method may be configured on the **code Templates** page, but all I can find is the generation of comments for delegates. Is this possible? What is taken from the `code` section to generate the delegate **method**, not the comment?